# 'At least one client secrets (Installed or web) should be set' error when using the Google Drive API in C# Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#

I just started learning programming.

I wanted to add a simple interface to upload images to my Google Drive account in my Windows Forms application. but I got different mistakes than I thought. The steps I have taken in short

I Referance this page : https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet

I downloaded the Google Drive API file and included it in my project.

Step 1 + Step 2

I pasted the code blog that Google specified on the reference page into my program CS file. and I replaced the name of my API with the definition in the code.

Step 3 +

new FileStream("**client_secret.json**",

but now I get the following error.

```
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("GoogleDriveApi.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }
```

**System.InvalidOperationException: 'At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set'**

[image: İmage1]

Comment: Can you confirm that your json file starts with {"installed":{"client_id":"your_clienntid_here","project_id":"your_project_id_here","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth".....? if not make sure you are using the correct json file